# Differences of order statistics for symmetric random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, symmetry, order-statistics

Take a sequence of $n$ i.i.d. random variables **symmetric around zero** and with zero expectation:
$$
\eta_1,\eta_2,\dots, \eta_n.
$$
Use standard order statistic notation and consider
$$
\eta_{(1)}\leq \eta_{(2)}\leq \dots \leq \eta_{(n)}.
$$
Let $L\subset \{1,\dots, n\}$ with cardinality $n_L$ and define the sets
$$
L_\eta\equiv \{i\in \{1,\dots, n\}: \eta_i 
\geq \eta_{(n_L)}\} \quad U_\eta\equiv \{i\in \{1,\dots, n\}: \eta_i 
\geq \eta_{(n-n_L)}\}
$$

**Question:** show that
$$
E\left(\sum_{i\in U_\eta} \eta_{(i)}-\sum_{i\in L_\eta}\eta_{(i)}\right)=0.
$$

The book says that symmetry is key here but I struggle to understand the result. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a proof for

$$
\mathbb E\left(\sum_{i\in \color{red}{U'_\eta}} \eta_{(i)}-\sum_{i\in \color{red}{L'_\eta}}\eta_{(i)}\right)=0.
$$

where
$$
\color{red}{L'_\eta}\equiv \{i\in \{1,\dots, n\}: \eta_i 
\color{red}{>} \eta_{(n_L)}\} \quad \color{red}{U'_\eta}\equiv \{i\in \{1,\dots, n\}: \eta_i 
\color{red}{>} \eta_{(n-n_L)}\}.
$$

**Discussion:**

**I think there is a typo in the book or the question.** Consider the following example: $n=3$, $\eta \sim U(-0.5,0.5)$. Then, the expectations of $\eta_{(1)}, \eta_{(2)}, \eta_{(3)}$ are $\frac{-1}{4}, 0, \frac{1}{4}$. Then, for the sets defined in the question and for $n_L=1$

$$
\mathbb E\left(\sum_{i\in {U_\eta}} \eta_{(i)}-\sum_{i\in {L_\eta}}\eta_{(i)}\right)=0+ \frac{1}{4} -\left (\frac{-1}{4}+ 0+ \frac{1}{4} \right) \neq 0.
$$

However, for the modified sets:

$$ \mathbb E\left(\sum_{i\in {U'_\eta}} \eta_{(i)}-\sum_{i\in {L'_\eta}}\eta_{(i)}\right)=\frac{1}{4} -\left (0+ \frac{1}{4} \right) =0.$$

**Proof:**

As $\eta_{(1)},\eta_{(2)},\cdots, \eta_{(n)}$ are the order statistics of $\eta_i, i=1, \dots, n$, then $-\eta_{(n)}\le -\eta_{(n-1)}\le \cdots \le -\eta_{(1)}$ are the order statistics of $-\eta_i, i=1, \dots n.$ From the symmetry assumption $$-\eta_i \stackrel{d}=\eta_i, i, \dots n,$$ which implies that

$$\eta_{(i)} \stackrel{d}= -\eta_{(n+1-i)}.$$

Moreover, we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\eta_{i}= \sum_{i=1}^{n_L}\eta_{(i)}+\sum_{i=n_L+1}^{n}\eta_{(i)},$$

which gives

$$\sum_{i\in L'_\eta}\eta_{(i)}=\sum_{i=n_L+1}^{n}\eta_{(i)}=\sum_{i=1}^n\eta_{i} -\sum_{i=1}^{n_L}\eta_{(i)}$$

Hence, using the above identity,

$$
\sum_{i\in U'_\eta} \eta_{(i)}-\sum_{i\in L'_\eta}\eta_{(i)}=\sum_{i=n-n_L+1}^{n}\eta_{(i)}-\sum_{i=1}^n\eta_{i} +\sum_{i=1}^{n_L}\eta_{(i)}=\sum_{i=1}^{n_L}\eta_{(n+1-i)} +\sum_{i=1}^{n_L}\eta_{(i)} -\sum_{i=1}^n\eta_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n_L} \big [\eta_{(n+i-1)}+\eta_{(i)} \big] -\sum_{i=1}^{n}\eta_{i}.
$$

Now, again from the symmetry assumption and $\eta_{(i)} \stackrel{d}= -\eta_{(n+1-i)}$, we have
$$ \mathbb E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n_L} \big [\eta_{(n+i-1)}+\eta_{(i)} \big] -\sum_{i=1}^{n}\eta_{i}\right)=0.
$$

Comment: Thanks. I think the first line has some typos.

Comment: "As .... are the order statistics of $-\eta_i$": I think it should be "of $\eta_{i}$", without the minus

Comment: @TEX you are welcome! I just fixed it.

Comment: Also, when you write "Hence,...", I don't get why we can write: $$ \sum_{i=n-n_L}^n \eta_{(i)}-\sum_{i=1}^n \eta_i+\sum_{i=1}^{n_L-1} \eta_{(i)}=\sum_{i=1}^{n_L-1}\eta_{(n+1-i)}+\sum_{i=n-n_L}^n \eta_{(i)}-\sum_{i=1}^n \eta_i$$

Comment: Suppose $n=7$ and $n_L=5$. Then $$\sum_{i=n-n_L}^n\eta_{(i)}=\eta_{(2)}+\eta_{(3)}+\dots+\eta_{(7)}$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^{n_L-1}\eta_{(n+1-i)}=\eta_{(7)}+\eta_{(6)}+\eta_{(5)}+\eta_{(4)}$$

Comment: And also, could you add details on the last step, where you conclude that the mean is zero? We know that $$E(\sum_{i=1}^{n_L-1} \eta_{(n+i-1)}+\eta_{(i)}-\sum_{i=1}^n \eta_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n_L-1} 2 E(\eta_{(i)})-\sum_{i=1}^n \times 0=\sum_{i=1}^{n_L-1} 2 E(\eta_{(i)})= ?$$

Comment: @TEX Note that as $\eta_{(i)} \stackrel{d}= -\eta_{(n+1-i)}$, the mean of $\eta_{(i)} +\eta_{(n+1-i)}$ is 0.

Comment: Thanks, understood. Could you read also my comment above, about the change of subscript in the summation? I am not sure I understand how the two sums can be equivalent.

Comment: Could you check the  updated answer? I think the question needs to be slightly revised.